# Native Promise in Chrome doesn't resolve

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, asynchronous, promise

I'm using Chrome v. 35, which is reported to provide native support for Promise. The browser does recognize the Promise constructor, but using it in the way shown in countless examples and documentation links on the web does not work.

Here is how I create the Promise:

```
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
            self.events.on("reply",function(event) {
                if (event.msgId === id) {
                    resolve(event.packet);//we get here, but fail to step into method resolve
                }
            });
            self.events.on("cancelReply",function(event) {
                if (event.msgId === id) {
                    reject(Error(event.msgId));
                }
            });
});
```

Invoking the callback "resolve" has no effect. In the debugger, the function is present, but stepping into it just passes control to the next line. And the "then" method on the promise is never invoked:

```
promise.then(function(result) {
   //we never get here
});
```

Can someone tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: The debugger won't step into `resolve` because it's native code. Are you sure that `resolve` is actually getting called (that the reply event is coming, and the id [which is defined where?]  matches)? Remember also that `promise.then` won't fire until the promise has had a chance to resolve during the next run loop.

Comment: You don't need promises here.

Comment: Because it's not right tool for event management. For example your promise will only work one time: until you resolve or reject it.

Comment: On the contrary, promises work well with (certain types of) events. Of course, you need to set up a promise for each expected event, which as you say will be fulfilled/rejected once at most, but we have no indication the OP does not realize that or is not doing that.

Comment: I realized the debugger was not stepping into the native code, and then I found an error that was preventing the promise.then call from being executed. So the way I have promise coded here is working after all.

Comment: And Yes I realize that the promise will only fire once. The event is a reply to a specific packet. So a promise is created for each packet sent, and the promise is fulfilled when a reply to the packet arrives. I do have one case that I need to code next where the packet is a "watch" packet, and numerous replies will be sent to that one packet. Would it be better to register a callback for that case, or to have the promise re-create itself each time it's fulfilled?

Comment: @dfsq Many times there are event emitter interfaces where you don't care about that. For example, XHR is event emitter interface where you map success event to resolve, abort, timeout and error events to reject, and simply don't care about the progress event (or take a callback for it separately).

Comment: @MidnightJava Please create a fiddle that reproduces this bug, I have been unable to do so. In addition, since native promises in Chrome lack unhandled rejection detection (use Bluebird, seriously), you have to append an error handler too at the end of the chain so errors won't get silenced automatically. Add a `.catch` too and log its output.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Sure, but this problem was basically a typo that prevented the promise from ever being fulfilled, not an uncaught error swallowed by the promise.

Comment: Here's a plunker you can start with. I used Promise and it seems to be working: http://plnkr.co/edit/UiyLly1AqfMb9OrWs2uA?p=preview

Comment: @torazaburo how is that a "but"? you're basically agreeing with me.

Comment: "*and then I found an error that was preventing the promise.then call from being executed*" - please, [write an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) about that

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Yes, I'm agreeing with you, just saying that was not the problem in this particular case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The debugger won't step into resolve because it's native code.

My suspicion is that a bug in your code is preventing `resolve` from actually getting called (perhaps the reply event is not coming, or the id doesn't match).

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment to the question, this was a cockpit error on my part. Promise is working as advertised in Chrome. Thanks everyone for all the helpful comments.

Comment: Resolve was being called. There was a problem in how Promise.then was being invoked, which I was missing while focussed on the red herring of the debugger not stepping into the resolve handler inside the Promise.